# Is it possible to send MMS using adb commands?

Tags: android, python, adb, mms

I was just wondering if there is any way to send an MMS using adb commands?
I know the that we can send SMS using adb, by the following code :

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:0123456789 --es sms_body "SMS\ BODY\ GOES\ HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
```

Is there any similar command that can be used to send MMS too? Is there a way to attach a file (image, audio, gif etc) from the sdcard while sending the message?
Or, is there a way to do this using any python libraries except Twilio?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I was recently looking for the same solution and came up with this after piecing together different info:

```
adb -s <deviceID> shell "am start -a android.intent.action.SEND --es address 
'<tel#>' --eu android.intent.extra.STREAM 'file:///<path to file>' -t 
'<filetype>'"
```

- deviceID = adb device ID
- tel# = telephone number
- path to file = path to file on device
- filetype = MIME type of the file

Note:  it will create a "Complete action using" popup and have to click Messages or whatever app you are using, but that was not an issue for me.